# How to resize/reposition controls of a Window, when the window size changes

Tags: c++, winapi

When using any program, resizing the window makes the controls change location to fit on the window. How do you do this using C++? I've seen a lot of C# examples, but C++ ones were no where.

Comment: If you use a GUI framework look for some builtin support. If you write to the raw winapi then handle the size events and adjust the child controls by hand.

Comment: I was hoping to do it with just winapi. I was thinking of how to do it manually, but figured there had to be some built in way. I suppose not :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) API in `WM_SIZE` message:

I create a sample and use the following code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hButton;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("OK"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON, 50, 50, 50, 50, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        return 0;
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        int cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        int cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);
        SetWindowPos(hButton, NULL, cxClient / 3, cyClient / 4, cxClient / 5, cyClient / 2, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The created button will be resized according to my resize window:

[image]

Comment: usually need move multiple(n) controls in window, in this case better use `BeginDeferWindowPos` + `DeferWindowPos`(n ) + `EndDeferWindowPos`. also usual need for every control select 2 point (left,top) and (right,bottom) and distance between point and one on parent border is constant

Comment: @RbMm Thank you for your supplement, I just propose some feasible methods, maybe you can post your answer.